# Deactivate a mousemove event after refreshing a webpage doesn't work

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

I'm using a jQuery `mousemove` event to track mouse activities.

For testing purposes, I'm calling `startActivityTracker()` in the developer console.
When the mouse is moved, `onActivity()` is called.
Then I run `stopActivityTracker()` and `onActivity()` is no longer called. This all works so far.

But when the website is refreshed (e.g. <kbd>F5</kbd>) after calling `startActivityTracker()`, `stopActivityTracker()` has no effect. In other words, `onActivity()` is still being called.
Is there any reference lost when refreshing the page?

```
function onActivity() {
    console.log('onActivity: ' + Math.random()) ;    
}

function startActivityTracker() {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        console.log('Tracker started.');
        $(document).mousemove(onActivity);        
    });
}

function stopActivityTracker() {
    console.log('Tracker stopped.');
    $(document).off('mousemove', onActivity);
}
```

Comment: I was not able to reproduce this issue. I have no issues at all. I call `startActivityTracker` on a button click and move mouse i can see the `console.logs` - If i refresh the page - i do not see the control log again. Until i call `startActivityTracker` ? Are you able to clarify more please

Answer (score 0):

**Try to change the function**

> ```
> function stopActivityTracker() {
>     console.log('Tracker stopped.');
>     $(document).off('mousemove');
> }
> ```

Comment: Thanks, I will give this a try. Will this not disable any (other) mousemove event (if there are any others) and not only the one that was started in startActivityTracker() ?

Comment: The code above will remove every mouse event, use **unbind**  to remove specific event.

Like this:  $(document).unbind('mousemove', onActivity);

Comment: off() is the same as unbind(). But as of jQuery 3.0, .unbind() has been deprecated. It was superseded by the .off() method since jQuery 1.7, so its use was already discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

In your **startActivityTracker** function you run :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
```

According to the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/ready/):

> The .ready() method offers a way to run JavaScript code as soon as the
> page's Document Object Model (DOM) becomes safe to manipulate.

Instead, in **stopActivityTracker** you don't wait for the ready event, so the [.off()](https://api.jquery.com/off/) method is executed before you attach the mousemove event:

```
$(document).mousemove(onActivity)
```

In order to solve this issue you need to change your **stopActivityTracker** to:

```
function stopActivityTracker() {
    $(document).ready(function () {
         console.log('Tracker stopped.');
         $(document).off('mousemove', onActivity);
    });
}
```

It works in the developer console because the dom is already **ready**.

Full code:

```js
function onActivity() {
    console.log('onActivity: ' + Math.random());
}

function startActivityTracker() {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        console.log('Tracker started.');
        $(document).mousemove(onActivity);
    });
}

function stopActivityTracker() {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        console.log('Tracker stopped.');
        $(document).off('mousemove', onActivity);
    });
}


$( document ).ready(function () {
    startActivityTracker();
    stopActivityTracker();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

In any case, I would suggest you to remove the ready event handler from your functions and call them inside a global ready event handler:

```js
function onActivity() {
    console.log('onActivity: ' + Math.random());
}

function startActivityTracker() {
    console.log('Tracker started.');
    $(document).mousemove(onActivity);
}

function stopActivityTracker() {
    console.log('Tracker stopped.');
    $(document).off('mousemove', onActivity);
}


$( document ).ready(function () {
    startActivityTracker();
    stopActivityTracker();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

In order to get the evidence your **stopActivityTracker** runs before **startActivityTracker** it's enough to stop the **onActivity** function after the first call:

```js
var onlyFirstTime = true;

function onActivity(e) {
    if (onlyFirstTime) {
        onlyFirstTime = false;
        console.log('onActivity: ' + Math.random()) ;
    }
}

function startActivityTracker() {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        console.log('Tracker started.');
        $(document).mousemove(onActivity);
    });
}

function stopActivityTracker() {
    console.log('Tracker stopped.');
    $(document).off('mousemove', onActivity);
}
startActivityTracker();
stopActivityTracker();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/pxhs9qer/

JS:

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        function onActivity() {
            $('#log').text('onActivity: ' + Math.random());
        }
        function startActivityTracker() {
            $('#status').text('on');
            $(document).on('mousemove', onActivity);
        }
        function stopActivityTracker() {
            $('#status').text('off');
            $(document).off('mousemove', onActivity);
        }
        $('#btn').on('change', function() {
            if (this.checked) {
                startActivityTracker();
            } else {
                stopActivityTracker();
            }
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Wrap your entire script in $(document).ready(), and use **on** along with **off**